# Setting up multiple validation for email and username when registering user in API post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm setting up a post call to register a new user. The code checks to see if an email exists in the User model. If not, then it creates a new user. However, I just realized I need to also check if the username already exists as well. I'm pretty new to setting up API calls so I'm not sure how to refactor/add in another fineOne call, or another method, to see if the username exists too before creating the new user.

```
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email already exists" });
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      });
    }
  });
});
```

So, I need to add code to see if the username exists. If it does, return a 404 message for it and continue to check if the email exists. Then i can add the new user.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little extra syntax for find with a disjunction. It looks like this:

```
User.findOne({ $or:[ { email: req.body.email }, { username: req.body.username } ]}).then...
```

Comment: Is there a way to access which value it found? So, if it found an email, i can return a 400 message saying "email already exists" or "username already exists" if it found a username

Comment: Yes.  There's also the possibility that the single found object matches both username and email.  Also, there's a case where one existing user has a duplicate email and another existing user has a duplicate username.  To catch all of these cases, use `find` instead of `findOne`, then iterate results, setting a bool if any found user has matching email, and setting another bool if any found user has matching username.  Those two bools now cover all cases: dup email, dup username or dup both.